# How to load multiple input field data with single ajax call?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to load product name and price by selecting the product code. but i coudn't. i try this way but at a time show name and price in one field.

This is my HTML page code.

```
<select name="" id="" class="code">
    <option value="">Select</option>
<?php
    $db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");

    $select = $db->query("select code from product");

    while (list($code) = $select->fetch_row()) {
        echo "<option value='$code'>$code</option>";
    }
?>
</select> <input type="text" class="name"> <input type="text" class="price">

<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".code").change(function(){
            var code = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url : 'select.php',
                method : 'POST',
                data : {code:code},
                success : function(echo){
                    $('.name').val(echo);
                    $('.price').val(echo);
                }
            });

        });
    })
</script>
```

This is php code

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");

$code = $_POST["code"];

$select = $db->query("select name, price from product where code='$code'");

list($name, $price) = $select->fetch_row();
echo $name;
echo $price;
```

?>

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must return data as a json and then you can get them on ajax response

```
<?php
echo json_encode(['name'=>$name,'price'=>$price]);

?>
```

your script:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".code").change(function(){
            var code = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url : 'select.php',
                method : 'POST',
                data : {code:code},
                success : function(echo){
                    $('.name').val(echo.name);
                    $('.price').val(echo.price);
                }
            });

        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: if your response header is not json you must parse json. response = JSON.parse(echo); and then response.name or response.price

Comment: Add to ajax this: dataType: 'json'. Then on success, the echo param contains your json from server.

Comment: you cant get echo.name ?